# Why does ServletRequest getAttribute() have different attributes than getAttributeNames()?

Tags: java, servlets, request

We run Apache infront of Tomcat and use mod_jk. Our single sign on Apache module sets information about the user which we can retrieve in Java with a [getAttribute()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) call.

```
String mobileNumber = request.getAttribute("WEBAUTH_LDAP_MOBILE");
```

This works fine. Now I wanted to retrieve all attributes and look for ones named with a prefix "WEBAUTH_LDAP_". I used [getAttributeNames()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttributeNames%28%29) for this.

```
Enumeration<String> enumeration = request.getAttributeNames();
```

to get the attribute names. To my surprise there is no attribute named "WEBAUTH_LDAP_MOBILE".
Is this expected? Is there a way to get all attributes? The JavaDoc makes it sound like something in getAttribute() should also be in getAttributeNames().

We are using Tomcat 6.0.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because any attributes set with mod_jk are available with `getAttribute()` but not through `getAttributeNames()`. According to the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html)

> You can retrieve the variables on Tomcat as request attributes via
>   request.getAttribute(attributeName). Note that the variables send via
>   JkEnvVar will not be listed in request.getAttributeNames().

I debugged through all the RequestWrappers (per BalusC's suggestion) and the underlying [request](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_28/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java) has an internal map of attributes which are used for `getAttributeNames()`. However, `getAttribute()` has a fall through to another object when the internal map's value is null. From the javadoc and documentation, this is working as designed.

This behavior has previously been reported as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47364), but the fix fails the TCK test:

> I looked at just including all the Tomcat internal attributes in the return
>   from getAttributeNames() but this causes problems with the Servlet 2.5 TCK
>   tests which expect that getAttributeNames() return only those attributes that
>   have been set via setAttribute().

So in short, `getAttributeNames()` will return attributes set with `setAttribute()` while `getAttribute()` can return attributes set through various other (internal) means.